# Redmine: How to override the model method visible_condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to override the model method with my plugin. I tried to create a new model Patch with method that should override like this:

```
require_dependency 'issue'

module IssuePatch
   def self.included(base) # :nodoc:
        base.send(:extend, ClassMethods)
        base.send(:include, InstanceMethods)
        base.class_eval do
            alias_method :visible_condition, :visible_condition_with_patch
        end
    end

    module ClassMethods

    end

    module InstanceMethods
        def visible_condition_with_patch(user, options={})

            <Do Something>
        end
    end
end


Rails.configuration.to_prepare do
    unless Issue.included_modules.include? IssuePatch
        # Issue.extend(InstanceMethods)
        Issue.send(:include, IssuePatch)
    end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to just redefine `visible_condition` in `InstanceMethods` module?

Comment: yeah i did it didn't work

Comment: what about overriding `visible_condition` inside `base.class_eval` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
require_dependency 'issue'

module IssuePatch
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      def visible_condition(user, options={})
        # do something
      end
    end
  end
end

Issue.send(:include, IssuePatch) unless Issue.included_modules.include?(IssuePatch)
```